# Position method to use with countletters method.

Tags: java

I have updated my code with two methods to use instead of the previous one.  But I'm still stuck and don't know How can I create and call a method that will replace Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)).  This method is suppose to receive a char, and return a int to be used with the countLetter() method.
The methods are:

```
int [] countLetters (string s), int pos(char x), and void printResults(int[] counts)
```

And yes, the int [] countLetters does need to return an array. I'm just wondering how to get the pos method to work instead of the character.isLetter.

Here is what I got so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CharCount {


public static Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    printResults(null);

}

/*
 * This method counts the number of occurrences in the inputed
 * string and returns the array with the count.
 */
public static int[] countletters(String s){

    int[] counts = new int[26];

       for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
           if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))){
              counts[(int)s.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
           }

    }
    return counts;
}
public static int pos(char x){
    return (int)charAt();
}

private static int charAt() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

/*
 * This method prints the results of the string count
 */
public static void printResults(int[] counts){

    String s = kbd.nextLine();
    counts = countletters(s.toLowerCase());
    System.out.println("\nLetter frequencies:");
    for (int i =0; i < counts.length; i++){
        if (counts[i] != 0){
            System.out.println((char)('a' + i) + " - " + counts[i] );
        }
    }
}
```

}

I feel like I need to start with `counts[(int)s.charAt(i) - 'a']++` and move it to the print method.

Thanks.

Comment: If this were my assignment, I'd start by creating the three methods, they'd be empty to start with, and then I'd try to start trying to fill each of them in, one at a time, testing each one as I go. Consider scrapping this question as it is perhaps being asked too prematurely, try to do this yourself, and then come on back with a more specific question if still stuck.

Comment: Note that your question has the `countLetters` method declared to return an array of int. Are you sure that this is correct, that it should be an array? And the second method isn't declared correctly or understandable -- please clarify it.

Comment: You should really try doing this bit yourself rather than getting the internet to do if for you. You've identified one bit of code to extract have a go.

Comment: I updated my program and managed to break down the 2nd method from the main program.  I just can't figure out what to break up in order to get isolate the POS method which i'm pretty sure is somehow using the if(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))){... but cant think of how to start in creating that on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't post code for you, as this is homework, but your pos method should return the relative position of the char in the alphabet. So 'a' would return 0, 'b' returns 1, 'c' returns 2,...

Myself, I'd change the char upper case or lower case, your choice, then subtract a number (or actually a char) from it, and return it.

Then the `pos(...)` method will be used in the `countletters(...)` method inside of the for loop to determine which array index to increment. Note that you should discared your `charAt()` method since it serves no purpose other than to confuse.